# Proving a ring is Boolean

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given $R$ is a ring, and $b$ is some positive integer such that $x + x^{2b + 1} = x^{2b} + x^{10b + 1}$ for all $x \in R$, prove that $R$ is Boolean, i.e. $x =x^2$ for all $x$ in $R$.

I am not sure where to begin with the problem, and what avenue of approach I should take such that my methodology is inclusive to all $x$ in R. 
Would it be feasible to convert this problem into matrix form, and then prove $A = A^2$?

Comment: You can try proving that R has characteristic 2.  To do this you can try substituting x = 1, 2, 3, ... and see what happens.

Comment: How would you "convert the problem" into "matrix form"?

Comment: @user4767: There is something amiss in your first sentence. Are you assuming that the equality holds for all $x\in R$, and are trying to deduce from *that* equality that $x=x^2$ for all $x$?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Since we assume $x$ in $R$, I want to deduce that $x =x^2$ for all $x$ in $R$.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Just to clarify, do you suggest that I simplify the equality so that 2x = 0?

Comment: @user4767: no, I just mean that it might be useful to show that R has characteristic 2 as a lemma.  Also, do you get to assume that R is commutative?  @Arturo: I have corrected the problem statement.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Well, if R is a Boolean ring then we know that it is commutative because all Boolean rings are commutative. I'm not sure how we can initially assume that, though.

Comment: @Qiaochu, user4767: I think Qiaochu's first comment is a suggestion to try $b=1,2,3\ldots$ (as opposed to $x$).

Comment: TO show $2 = 0$ in $R$ evaluate the identity at $x = -1$.

Comment: @Bill: It's unclear if the ring is assumed to have an identity, but you don't have to; as you had originally suggested, playing with the identity with $x$ and with $-x$ readily yields that $x+x=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Arturo: no, my suggestion was to try x = 1, 1 + 1, ... and take the gcds (I assumed the ring has an identity).

Comment: found a really great paper that could be of service: http://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/Volume17_4/749015.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problem usually succumbs to some sort of "clever choice" of $x$'s to plug in and manipulate. I don't have a full answer for you, but here's Bill's suggestion for showing that such a ring has characteristic $2$ (a necessary condition for being Boolean). Let $a\in R$. Evaluating the identity at $a$ and at $-a$, we have:
\begin{align*}
a + a^{2b+1} &= a^{2b} + a^{10b+1}\\
-a -a^{2b+1} &= a^{2b} - a^{10b+1}
\end{align*}
Adding both equalities we obtain $2a^{2b}=0$. Now, using the fact that $a=a^{2b}+a^{10b-1}-a^{2b+1}$, we have:
$$2a = 2a^{2b} + 2a^{10b-1}-2a^{2b+1} = 0 + 2a^{2b}a^{8b-1} - 2a^{2b}a = 0,$$
so for all $a\in R$ we have $a+a=0$.

I don't have any clever manipulations to suggest for proving $a=a^2$ for all $a$, alas. I tried a few last night, and didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Since this is only a very partial answer, and was made following Bill's hint, I've marked it "community wiki." A bit of an abuse of community wiki, I know, but still.